# First order differential equation $x'=e^x\sin(t)$, $x(\pi/2)=0$ maximal interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$x=x(t)$$
>   $$x'=e^x\sin(t)$$
>   $$x(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$

I've solved the equation with: $x'=e^xsin(t)$ $\to$ $\frac{1}{e^x}x'=sin(t)$

The answer I got was $x=-ln(cos(t)-C)$. I plugged in $x(\pi/2)=0$ then I got $x=-ln(cos(t))$.

I'm to determine the maximal interval by $t=\pi/2$, but I don't understand the question. If $t$ is already given, then what interval am I supposed to be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is $x(t)=-\ln (1+\cos \,t)$. This is well defined as long as $1+\cos \, t >0$. The largest interval around $\pi /2$ on which $1+\cos \, t >0$ is $(-\pi, \pi)$.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i understand my solution was wrong. But could you explain 'largest interval around $π/2$ on which $1+cost>0$ is $(−π,π)$' this part please?

Comment: Once you obtain the solution you have to see where it is defined and where it really satisfies the given IVP. In this case $1+\cos \,t \geq 0$ for all $t$ so logarithm of this defined whenever $1+\cos \,t \neq 0$. Look for the nearest 'trouble points': the points nearest to $\frac {\pi} 2$ at which $1+\cos \,t = 0$. These are $\pi$ and $-\pi$. The largest interval around $\frac {\pi} 2$ not containing these trouble spots is $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer!